# Display Apple's call out bubble on custom MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a custom `MKAnnotation` and all the annotations are all in the right place and have followed the MKAnnotation's Protocol but i want to display the standard call out bubble when the user taps on the annotation, can I do this or do I have the implement a custom call out bubble?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `canShowCallout` property to `YES` for the `MKAnnotationView` you create to represent your particular `MKAnnotation`.

The call out will use the `title` property from your `MKAnnotation` as it's title, and also the `subtitle` property if it is not `nil`.

You can set the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` and `rightCalloutAccessoryView` properties on the `MKAnnotationView` if you want or need to. The left view is usually a `UIImageView` with an icon, and the right view is usually a `UIButton` that acts as a detail disclosure button.

Comment: @user443444: You are using a `MKPinAnnotationView`, and you are sure you have set at least the `title` property on the `MKAnnotation` that you use to init the `MKPinAnnotationView` with?